# Intiate web3 object in server.js or in each controller

Tags: web3js, nodejs

I was creating a dApp on ethereum. The backend I am using is nodejs. While creating the server, I faced a confusion.

Should I create a web3 instance on the server or on each controller?

I cannot find any resources which say what is the best practise for it.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a module called `ethereum.ts` like below:

```
import Web3 from "web3";
const web3 = new Web3(process.env.MAINNET);
export default new (class Ethereum {
   method1(){}
   method2(){}
})()
```

and import it wherever you want to use it

`controller.ts` :

```
 import Ethereum from "../../utils/ethereum";

 Ethereum.method1()
```